# Docker cant find sys.path

Tags: python, docker

I have an app I am trying to dockerize. When I run it locally a part of the app stores information in the `/tmp` folder, specifically `/tmp/importedlibrary/lib/site-packages`. This works fine running locally. However when I attempt to create a docker image the process fails.

```
    return [e for e in sys.path if 'site-packages' in e][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

No paths appear in sys.path so there is nothing to index and the process fails. Why can't docker work with the sys.path variable and what is the difference when running locally?

Comment: It is because you are accessing the first element from an empty list if `site-packages` does not appear in `sys.path`. why don't you add a try catch condition to address that?

Comment: I'm wondering why site-packages does not appear. I cannot add a try catch because the code comes from a third party library I am trying not to modify. I just want to integrate my code.